# Django: ContentTypes during migration while running tests

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I migrated a `ForeignKey` to a `GenericForeignKey`, using the `contrib.contenttypes` framework. To access the `ContentType` object I need to migrate the data, I used this code:

```
ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')

my_model_content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
    app_label='my_app',
    model='my_model'
)
```

The migration works when I run `manage.py migrate`, and I can then play with the updated model in the shell without problems.

However, when I attempt to run `manage.py test`, I get the following error in the `ContentTypes.object.get()` line:

```
__fake__.DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

Querying for `ContentType.objects.all()` at that time returns an empty queryset.

I have tried (as directed by another answer here in SO) to run this before my query, but to no avail:

```
update_contenttypes(apps.app_configs['contenttypes'])
update_contenttypes(apps.app_configs['my_app'])
```

How can I ensure that the `ContentType` rows exist at that point in the test database migration?

Comment: This exact situation just happened to me.  Thanks for describing it so well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me. First, import `update_contenttypes`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes
```

Second, list the initial `ContentType` migration as a dependency:

```
dependencies = [
    ('contenttypes', '0001_initial'),
    ...
]
```

Finally, in the `forward` migration function (invoked via `RunPython` in the migration `operations`):

```
# Ensure ContentType objects exist at this point:
app_config = apps.get_app_config('my_app')
app_config.models_module = app_config.models_module or True

update_contenttypes(app_config)
```

You may need to run the above code for more than one `app_config`. You can obtain the all the `app_config` objects using `apps.get_app_configs()` and iterate.

Comment: This doesn't work in 1.11: `from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_contenttypes`

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28092 Renamed to create_contenttypes

Comment: This worked for me in Django 1.11 using the renamed `update_contenttypes`.

Comment: Had to change the `app_config.models_module = app_config.models_module or True`  line to just `app_config.models_module = True` and it worked for me on Django 3.2